# How to dissect corba GIOP data with lua in wireshark

Tags: lua, wireshark, corba, wireshark-dissector

Is there any other way than idl2wrs&compilation of wireshark to properly interpret the data in CORBA GIOP protocol?

I was actually thinking about Lua but cannot find anything like  register_giop_user_module

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have IDL file and I know the content of the message.
I just don't want to recompile wireshark with every update.
Having a Lua-based dissector sounds great but I cannot find any how-to-do-it since GIOP dissector is based on heuristic not on e.g. tcp.port

Answer (score 0):

GIOP is not a self-describing protocol when encoded for transmission. You'll always need the IDL to interpret the payload bytes on the wire. The idl2wrs tool works by coupling the IDL with the bytes found through snooping, so unless you have another tool available that works on a similar principle, you'll be out of luck.